# How to find specific part of line from file and make list of them?

Tags: list, file, python-3.x

Okay so if my file looks like this:

"1111-11-11";1;99.9;11;11.1;11.1

"2222-22-22";2;88.8;22;22.2;22.2

"3333-33-33";3;77.7;3.3;33.3;33.3

How I can read only parts "99.9", "88.8" and "77.7" from that file and make a list [99.9, 88.8, 77.7]? Basically I want to find parts after n semicolons.

Comment: what is the file type? is the data always at the form of "XXXX-XX-XX; number; the value that you want, other stuff?

Comment: Data is .csv file and yes it's always same type, but lenght of values are different.

Comment: what do you mean by length of values ? Is the data you want always at the same position ?

Comment: Data is alway between same semicolons, but not in same position.

Comment: Can you give an actual example of the way your data is stored?

Answer (score 0):

You can open the file and read each line with the `open` command for csv your code might look like:

```
import csv
with open('filename.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    listOfRows = list(reader)
```

You will now have a list of lines, each line requires some processing. 
if you lines always have the same structure you can split them by a ;

```
list_in_line= line.split(";")
```

and get the third element in that line.

Please show us some of your work, or better explain the structure of your data

Comment: for csv you will need to read about this https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html